# Must declare the scalar variable @Stringkey

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to create a SQL script that fills a table with a new primary key.

what i currently have from internet searches is the following

```
DECLARE @IntVariable int;
DECLARE @Stringkey varchar(2);
DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(500);
DECLARE @Intupdater nvarchar(500);

SET @IntVariable = 00000001;
SET @Stringkey = 'CD';

SET @SQLString = N'UPDATE Tri_Damen_Live.trimergo.calendar_details SET details_key = @Stringkey + @IntVariable';
SET @Intupdater = N'@IntVariable = @IntVariable+1'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString , N'@IntVariable INT' , N'@Stringkey VARCHAR(2)', @IntVariable, @Stringkey;
```

The errors I get with this are

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near '='.
>   Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 1
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@Stringkey".

I have a few questions about my problem and hope someone might be able to help me

First question : it seems my `int` increaser is wrong. is there a way to make a update variable statement for the int?

Second : I declared the int as 00000001. But I doubt it stays like this. The reason I do this is because the key needs to be a set 10 characters long in total (example 'CD00000001' etc) does this work like this or is there another way?

Third question : as the topic stated. The 'Must declare the scalar variable "@Stringkey".' error. I have removed the stringkey part but then it says the same error about the `Int` variable. I declared them at the top and set them as well. What am I missing?

Side information :

this function will be used for multiple databases with varying table sizes. So I need this kind of function to account that it does not have a set amount of update statements.

The primary key that is created here must be a string (`Varchar(10)`) that is ALWAYS 10 characters long. Seems like a silly requirement but it has been chosen to use this system.

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2012 to run this in.

Comment: After `SET @IntVariable = 00000001;` the value of that variable (of type *int*) is just `1`. Leading zeroes have no meaning for a number.

Comment: Yeah i was like 95% sure this was not going to work like I hoped. but figured i might as wel give it a shot to see.

Comment: If the primary key is **always** 10 characters long - make it a `CHAR(10)` and save yourself 2 bytes (per entry) of unnecessary overhead! That's quite important if your primary key is also the clustering key

Answer (score 3):

1 You can't add an int to a string like that. You need to convert the `int` to a string

```
   @Stringkey + convert(varchar(10),@IntVariable)
```

2 An int is a number. If you want it to be formatted, you need to do that yourself.

```
   SET details_key = @Stringkey + right(''0000000000''+convert(varchar(8),@IntVariable),8)
```

3 Your variable declaration in `sp_executesql` should be

```
N'@IntVariable INT, @Stringkey VARCHAR(2)'
```

ie

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString , N'@IntVariable INT, @Stringkey VARCHAR(2)', @IntVariable, @Stringkey;
```

Alternatively, you might consider using a `SEQUENCE` - see http://raresql.com/2013/06/21/sql-server-2012-how-to-generate-a-varchar-sequence-number-using-sequence-object/

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter to [`sp_executesql`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) should be a *single* string containing *all* parameter definitions:

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString , N'@IntVariable INT,@Stringkey VARCHAR(2)', @IntVariable, @Stringkey;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @SQLString = N'UPDATE Tri_Damen_Live.trimergo.calendar_details SET details_key = @Stringkey + @IntVariable';
```

You are trying to concat `@Stringkey + @IntVariable` => ***(string + int)*** where you should convert the *@IntVariable* to varchar